# Is is safe to store JWT in windows object and retrieve it whenever needed

Tags: angular, reactjs

I am getting an access token(JWT) in the Url . 
Ex: http://1.2.3.4:8000/ABCService/ValidateID?Token=eyJqa3UiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvb2F1dGgueGZpbml0eS5jb2.

Is it safe to store this token in windows object ? Ex: window.jwt = Token

If "yes" how it can be implemented(extract the JWT from Window object and perform next operations like validate JWT etc) in React JS ...

FYI: I did it using cookie and HTML5 web storages like (local & Session)... I wanted to make my website more secure ... that's why i have chosen to store it in window

Comment: Have you considered storing it in a cookie or local storage? What would be the reason to store it on the window?

Comment: I did it using cookie and HTML5 web storages like (local & Session)... I wanted to make my website more secure ... that's why i have choosen to store it in window..

Comment: Storing it in the `window` object isn't any more or less secure than storing it in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` (which actually resides on the `window` object as `window.localStorage`). These are readable from JavaScript hence obtainable in case of an XSS attack.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not safe. In case of an XSS attack where JavaScript is injected and run on your website, it is just as easy to read your `window.jwt` as it is to read `document.cookie`, `window.localStorage` or `window.sessionStorage`.

JWT are great for server-to-server communication and mobile-to-server communication, but for browser-to-server communication JWT is not suitable. Cookies (declared as "Secure" and "HttpOnly" and with "SameSite" declared as "Strict") is the safest.